# Workflow 'was cancelled by system account'

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, information-management, information-policy, information-lifecycle-management

I am trying to make a simple 2010 workflow in SP Designer, I am using SP 2013.  The workflow is made at the List Level: [Email MyUserGroup].  Manual start is enabled.  I can successfully trigger the manual start on this workflow and it sent an email on site collection A, but the same workflow configuration will not work on site collection B.

I am the SharePoint Administrator for the whole farm, including Site Collection A & B, **although I am logged in as a user** when I manually trigger the workflows.

I found a [similar issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69330/workflow-was-canceled-by-system-account?rq=1) - the error code I have is the same.  I have also read that the 'System Account' is to blame for these instances, though I am puzzled why the workflow functions on site collection A but not B.

To give some more details, when I look at the Workflow Status page I see the following:

- Initiator: [MyUserName]
- Status: Failed to start
- Event Type: Workflow cancelled
- User ID: System Account
- Description: Workflow [MyWorkflowName] was cancelled by System Account.

I will test tonight whether the Information Management Policy Setting is able to start the workflow and send the email message.  It should be triggered 0 days after creation date (today).

Thanks for any feedback.
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigated the other Answer by gachCoder, but my workflow is a 2010 one.  But I had a similar kind of workflow error again.

I found the Answer by Hardik in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185571/failed-on-start-workflow-was-canceled-by-system-account) solved my issue.

**24/09/2018 Update to Answer:** you might also like to read [this Answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177977/is-it-safe-to-deactivate-workflow-feature) relating to whether or not it is safe to deactivate and reactivate a workflow Site Feature (it seems like running workflows would/could be lost).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't enabled workflow app permissions. Please try with below link and i hope this will resolve your issue.

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Comment: I've since found that this Answer relates to Sharepoint 2013 workflows, rather than Sharepoint 2010 workflows - my question related to 2010 workflows.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the ULS logs for SharePoint and spot an error along the lines of below -

```
Type System.CodeDom.CodeBinaryOperatorExpression is not marked as authorized in the application configuration file.
```

Then you're likely missing some required Assembly Authorizations in web.config which is a known issue with the latest updates.

There's plenty of info online and I've also written a short article on fixing this - https://spandcrm.com/2018/10/11/sharepoint-2013-workflows-failing-with-failed-to-start-error/

Answer (score 0):

For us, sharepoint 2013, the issue was due to last KB causing an issue. Fixed by modifying the web.config of each web servers using [this script](https://gist.github.com/seaSide974/be74ed839bff3001be01468b41cf69bb) which will add the lines in the web config of each WFE. Make sure your backup your web.Config before running this :

[Additional Information about the KB causing the issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/)